# Ruby CSV in Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, import

I read a CSV file. This file looks like this

```
1.00 cm; 2.00cm ; 3.00 cm; ... ; 100 cm
2.00 cm; 4.00 cm; 6.00 cm; ... ; 100 cm
4.00 cm; 8.00 cm; 12.00 cm; ... ; 100cm
8.00 cm; 16.00 cm; 24.00 cm; ... ; 100cm
```

I have already written the following code

```
CSV.foreach("/Users/testUser/Entwicklung/coverrechner/CoverPaperDE.csv", col_sep: ';') do |row|
      puts row[0]
end
```

This produces the following output:

```
1.00 cm
2.00 cm
4.00 cm
8.00 cm
```

**Example:**
My matrix is constructed

```
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4

2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4

3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4

4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4
```

I want the following output

```
1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 1.2 2.2 3.2 4.2 ... 4.4
```

How does it work?

Comment: What you want ? I am not getting. Expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the first element of the first row and the third element of the last row?

```
first = last = nil
CSV.foreach("/Users/testUser/Entwicklung/coverrechner/CoverPaperDE.csv", col_sep: ';') do |row|
  first ||= row[0]
  last = row[3]
end

puts "first is #{first} and last is #{last}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, this does give the exact expected output:

```
 csv_str = "1.00 cm; 2.00cm ; 3.00 cm; ... ; 100 cm\n2.00 cm; 4.00 cm; 6.00 cm; ... ; 100 cm\n4.00 cm; 8.00 cm; 12.00 cm; ... ; 100cm\n8.00 cm; 16.00 cm; 24.00 cm; ... ; 100cm"
CSV.parse(csv_str, col_sep: ';') do |row|
   puts row[0]
end
```

output:

```
1.00 cm
2.00 cm
4.00 cm
8.00 cm
```

(CSV.parse is the same as your method, just parsing a string instead of using a file, used for the case of a [sscce](http://sscce.org/))